# loc filter resulting in MemoryError, was running fine yesterday

Tags: python, pandas

```
insp_all_final2=insp_all_final.loc[:,
['INSPECTION_ID','INSP_LEVEL_CODE','INSP_DATE','INSP_TIME','REPORT_STATE','
TOTAL_VIOL','TOTAL_OOS','DEPTID','JOBCODE','JOB_DESC','DRVR_LIC_NBR']]
```

I am running the above code and persistently getting "MemoryError".

Till yesterday, it was working just fine. And the funny part is, there is still enough RAM in the system. I have used `gc.collect()` but still no avail. Please help or provide an alternative.

Comment: Interesting, it should works. Very similar is `insp_all_final2=insp_all_final[['INSPECTION_ID','INSP_LEVEL_CODE','INSP_DATE','INSP_TIME','REPORT_STATE','TOTAL_VIOL','TOTAL_OOS','DEPTID','JOBCODE','JOB_DESC','DRVR_LIC_NBR']]`. It seems there is more data. Also is possible use [`usecols`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#filtering-columns-usecols) for filter in `read_csv` ?

Comment: Or sometimes help restart PC :)

Comment: @PRMoureau - Yaar please be serious. 
jezrael - Did already

Comment: @Ankit - and same data as tommorow? same `len(df)` ?

Comment: @jezrael - yes, the same length and same data frame, I also was flabbergasted

Comment: Did you isolate this specific code sample to be guilty ? or is there another part in the code that could throw the error ? maybe show us what's before this line

Comment: Before this, I am merging this data frame with another and that is also working good. For that matter, if I try to parse any data frame to a new data frame, it's throwing a same error. I tried resetting index of this DF. Inplace =FALSE is not working but inplace=TRUE is working. It's pretty strange

Comment: Yes, the code is running isolated in jupyter notebook's individual cell and it is working fine now. God knows what has happened. Looks like :
@PRMoureau - Your suggestion to wait for monday worked, Hahahaha...!!!

Comment: @Ankit i told you !! i will post an answer to explain this _sunday behavior_ ... but someone is deleting all my best jokes (i'm kinda going too far ? i hope you didn't take this the wrong way)

Comment: Not at all dude